# Limit logs in kubernetes

Tags: logging, kubernetes, limit, kubernetes-pod

I'm running into issues because my containers are producing too much log output. This apparently causes the reserved space to run out and evicts the pods with message `The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container XYZ was using 1412Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.`

Is there any way to tell kubernetes to just forget about old logs? I would be perfectly fine with saying "10MB of logs per pod are more than enough", but I can't find any place to specify such a thing.

Whether this is a limit in time or size does not matter to me that much, as long as I can keep my pods alive. This is for a development environment, so log retention is not crucial at all.

Comment: Do you write logs to a file inside your container? Maybe a solution could be to disable this output. All common log aggregation systems use the stdout/stderr output which is also written to disk by your container runtime and scraped from there.

Comment: @alexzimmer96 I don't write logs to a file. Everything just goes to stdout/stderr. I only follow logs using `kubectl logs`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the container engine is docker in which case, you can configure docker to limit the logs written by your pod(s) container(s).

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

Comment: I am indeed using docker, so this looks promising. Thanks for sharing. I'll configure and hope I never see those PODs evicted...

Comment: @stefan - did you resolve this issue? And if so, was it related to the link provided here? Can you provide some details? Thanks.

Comment: @grt3kl I never encountered the issue again, yet that sadly doesn't mean that it was fixed. I'm quite confident that it was fixed, so I'd advise to just use the resources in the two answers provided (they essentially say the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

*This is a Community Wiki answer so feel free to edit it and add any additional details you consider important.*

As [William](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6722605/william) has already answered this question, I'm only going to add a few details to make this more complete.

Please take a look at [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) in the official kubernetes docs. As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level) *"Kubernetes currently is not responsible for rotating logs, but rather a deployment tool should set up a solution to address that."*

If your container runtime happens to be docker, you can set up your log rotation policy by editing/creating:

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

(on Linux host)

or:

```
C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json
```

(on Windows host)

which may look as follows:

```
{
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "10m",
    "max-file": "3",
    "labels": "production_status",
    "env": "os,customer"
  }
}
```